# How to use javascript webworker in webpack?

Tags: javascript, npm, web-worker

i'm trying to use web workers in my web app but  i'm having a hard time. Adding a new entry to the `webpack.config.js` does not work.

so, I'm trying to use the npm package called `worker-loader` but there is no proper example on how to use it. All of my attempts to use it has failed. Can you guys please show me a simple example on how to use it.

```
import Worker from "worker-loader!./Worker.js";
const myworker = new Worker();
myworker.postMessage(songs);
myworker.onmessage = function(Data) {
//do something
}
```

my webpack.config.js file is like this with

```
 entry: __dirname + "/js/index.js",
 output: {
 path: __dirname + "/dist",
 filename: "bundle.js"
 },  
{
  module: {
    rules: [
     {
    test: /\.worker\.js$/,
    use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
  }
]
}
}
```

My server tells me the following:

```
"GET /279b1e1fcb403131377a.worker.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

Since my `279b1e1fcb403131377a.worker.js` is inside `/dist` its giving me 404 error. How can i make the request to go inside `/dist`.

Comment: Note than in case of webpack v3, the latest version you can use is worker-loader@1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples given on the official Github page:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader

That should easily get you going.

Comment: So please state an actual error message or show what you have tried here. We can not help you if you don't put in the effort to create a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask